# Passing a huge 2d array between 2 view controllers

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

I usually use a segue to pass some data between 2 ViewControllers. But now I have a 2D array (About 40Meg of data and in the future it  may go to over 100Meg. It's a .json file). I read a few articles that tell all the different ways. But most ways (if not all) will make a copy of that data, and that takes time (in the launch screen it's acceptable but not when switching of ViewControllers). What method would you recommend? Putting my huge array as a global works fine, but it is frowned by many.

Comment: Use a wrapper class. Make your array be the property of a class and pass that object instead.  Since objects are passed by reference, it will be fast.

Comment: Or maybe reconsider if you really need to pass so much data between your view controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ArrayWapper {
    var array: [[Int]] = [[]] // Set your array .
}
```

And send an instance from that class to the second `UIViewController` 
as, **@vacawama** mentioned since its class it will pass the reference rather than a value copy of that array.

So in the second `UIViewController` you would have a variable of `ArrayWapper` class type, instead of simply `[[Int]]` array.